# Server not reading headers correctly - Issues with proxying and IP address retrieval in a Node.js and Nginx setup

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy, certbot

I'm facing a problem with my server setup where it is not able to read the headers of a request correctly. I have a VPS that uses proxies to redirect users to my application. I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy, and the application is built with Node.js and Express. The issue I'm experiencing is that the application is returning the IP address of the proxy instead of the user's IP address, despite setting the "trust proxy" option to true.
Here's my Nginx configuration for the proxy, I'm also using Certbot for HTTPS:

```
server {
  server_name api.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://31.190.113.56:8800;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And this is the code for my Express app:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  var ip = req.ip; 
  if (ip.substr(0,7) == '::ffff:') { 
    ip = ip.substr(7);
  }

  res.json({"ip": ip, "protocol": req.protocol, "headers": req.headers['x-forwarded-for']});
});

app.listen(8800)
```

When I visit /test, the response shows the IP address of the proxy instead of the user's IP address.

I was expecting the application to send the user's IP address as a JSON response instead of the proxy's IP address.
I've tried setting the "trust proxy" option to true, but it's still not working as expected.

I followed this documentation to setup nginx: https://github.com/safak/youtube/tree/mern-deployment